# Product image at j2store cart

Tags: joomla-3.x, e-commerce

j2store use thumbimage and mainimage  instead of joomla article intro and full image for show image product at j2store cart and order invoice

[image]

I decided to use intro image in article instead of j2store thumbnail image for show at j2store cart and invoice

[image]

[image]

this code for j2store cart and checkout that load thumb image product

```
<?php
    $registry = new JRegistry;
    $registry->loadString($item->orderitem_params);
    $item->params = $registry;
    $thumb_image = $item->params->get('thumb_image', '');
    $back_order_text = $item->params->get('back_order_item', '');
?>
```

and this code for show image at cart

```
<?php if($this->params->get('show_thumb_cart', 1) && !empty($thumb_image)): ?>
    <span class="cart-thumb-image">
    <a href="<?php echo $item->cartitem->product_view_url;?>">
        <img alt="<?php echo $item->orderitem_name; ?>" src="<?php echo $thumb_image; ?>" >
        </a>
    </span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

now I want use joomla article intro image show at cart
How to render and show joomla intro image at cart ?

Answer (score 1):

Cart view doesn't load Joomla images so you have to retrieve them. This can be done in the layout override or with a plugin. There are several plugin events that could be used. I'm using `onJ2StoreBeforeDisplayCart` because it passes all items at once. This allows to run a single query for all products in cart.

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;

class plgJ2StoreCartimage extends CMSPlugin
{
    protected $db;

    public function onJ2StoreBeforeDisplayCart($items)
    {
        // Get article IDs.
        $ids = array_column($items, 'product_source_id');

        // Get article images from the database.
        $query = $this->db->getQuery(true)
            ->select($this->db->quoteName(array('id', 'images')))
            ->from($this->db->quoteName('#__content'))
            ->where($this->db->quoteName('id') . ' IN (' . implode(',', $ids) . ')');

        // Index on ID for easy access.
        $data = $this->db->setQuery($query)->loadObjectList('id');

        foreach ($items as $item)
        {
            $images = json_decode($data[$item->product_source_id]->images);
            $item->thumb_image = $images->image_intro;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not familiar with J2Store but I noticed product object contains `$product_source` property which defines which extension the product belongs to (e.g. `com_content`). Assuming that it's possible to store products in multiple extensions, you might want to check the extension before getting the IDs and running the query:

```
$ids = [];

foreach ($items as $item)
{
    if ($item->product_source === 'com_content')
    {
        $ids[] = $item->product_source_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you ..It is possible to explain more ? Where do I put the codes?

Comment: You would put this in a new PHP file. Also create a manifest XML file. Then zip them together and install through Extension Manager. You can install this plugin in `j2store` group so in manifest file's `<extension>` tag use `group="j2store"`. See [Creating a Plugin for Joomla](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla) documentation for details.